# iOS Switch On/Off GPS without user intervention

Tags: ios, swift, gps, location-services, intervention

I'm developing an app where I need to `switch on`/`switch off` `GPS` automatically without user intervention.

Note:The application is for In-house purpose.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't toggle the GPS. The GPS will always be on unless your airplane mode is on. You can pause your CoreLocation datafeed but I highly doubt that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When i install the application user will get the popup to provide permission to access the location services. Can I mask that user permission and also switch on the location services automatically ??

Comment: @Harsha87 you can't do anything with the pop-up. But by code you can startUpdatingLocation and stopUpdatingLocation.

Comment: Of course not, that would be violating the user's privacy and it's impossible in iOS.